# Splitting a string at a certain character in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

In this code, I'm trying to split a string at a definite position, but it doesn't work and i'm not sure what to put, knowing that I'm trying to have it in the format "xy" without spaces, commas, anything.

```
import java.util.*;

  public class xy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println("Enter a number with the format 'xy'. x is the row number and y the column number.");
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      String[] xy = scanner.nextLine().split(charAt(1)); // not sure what to put here so I tried charAt but it doesn't work
      String x = xy [0];
      String y = xy [1];
    }
}
```

Comment: [`String.substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) to get sub-strings, or `String.charAt()` to get single characters. Notice that neither returns an array but only one string/char.

Comment: Can you add a little more description? what kind of input are you expecting? is it going to be the same type of input every time? Is there going to be a specific character preceding and following the user's entered 'xy' ?

Comment: Please explain ["doesn't work"](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this code, I'm trying to split a string at a definite position, but it doesn't work and i'm not sure what to put, knowing that I'm trying to have it in the format "xy" without spaces, commas, anything

You don't have to use split, there is no delimiter in the input received. Since the expected input is of `xy`. Receive it as a String and use charAt:

```
String input = scn.nextLine();
char x = input.charAt(0);
char y = input.charAt(1);
```

Or

```
String x = input.substring(0, 1);
String y = input.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you don't need to split. You basically know that the first string should go from index 0 to n-1, and then you got a second string from n-1 to "length".

Thus: don't split; simply call [substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) twice, and give the required numbers.

And as you **only** deal with two chards in the first place; just go:

```
char x = str.charAt(0);
char y = str.charAt(1);
```

Done.

Comment: This is a good idea, but what if the row or column is greater than 9?

Comment: @Sentinel In that case OP needs to change accepted format. Otherwise we can't know if 123 means 12 3 or 1 23. But this question is about xy format.

Comment: @Sentinel Then the expected input should not be xy, because there is no way to determine which digit belongs to x and y.

Comment: @Sentinel How would "you" split a value like 113? Is that 11/3 or 1/13 ... in that sense: the user would have to clarify his requirements then!

Comment: @GhostCat I agree! Just wanted to make sure it was noted

Comment: the row number is only 3 and the column number is only 4, so no 1 23 or 12 3.